# PHP : relay resource request through different server

Tags: php, curl, file-get-contents

I have the following situation, trying to clearify with a 'scheme'.

On a webapplication, we are showing resources comming from **server3**. But because **server3** is a intranet endpoint, we are loading the resource through some extra steps. Each server has a `Apache` running to cap the incomming requests.

The infra setup has some 'restrictions':

- **Server 1** contains the webapplication
- **Server 2** is only reachable by server1, and can't host the webapplication. And acts as a 'entry' point to server 3, restricted access only for requests comming from server1 (intranet server)
- **Server 3** (resources that need to be shown on the webapplication) is only reachable by server 2. Server 3 is an intranet server.

[image: Overview situation]

As you see on the scheme above, loading a resources takes some steps. I'm wondering if there are any better ways within `php` to stream contents from **server3** through **server2** initiated on **server1.** Without having to transport the content on each step.

I've been looking at `file_get_contents` in combination with `stream_context_create`. But not sure if this is possible relaying the request through a server in the middle.

I've tried something like this (stripdown):

```
$opts = array(
    'http' => array(
        'timeout' => 10,
        'proxy' => 'tcp://server2:port', 
        'request_fulluri' => true
    )
);
$context = stream_context_create($opts);
$data = file_get_contents('server3/files/footer.png', false, $context);
echo $data;
```

Any expertise is welcome. 
Thanks!